# Redirecting to localhost/? when using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and was trying to create a small login form. The problema i am having is that sometimes (yes, sometimes) when i run my aplication it redirects me to localhost/?, showing a list of all the files of in the project folder, like this:

localhost - /

11/10/2015    12:55         7130 AngularJsPrueba.csproj

11/10/2015    12:55         1086 AngularJsPrueba.csproj.user

11/10/2015    13:10         bin

11/10/2015    10:44           16 dashboard.html

11/10/2015    13:10          769 login.html

11/10/2015     9:55         obj

11/10/2015    12:52          711 packages.config

11/10/2015     9:55         Properties

11/10/2015    12:52         Scripts

11/10/2015    11:37          813 Web.config

11/10/2015     9:55         1299 Web.Debug.config

11/10/2015     9:55         1360 Web.Release.config

You may also want to know that this also happens when i try to access another page from my application ans you will see further. My code is the following, 
For the html:

```
    <html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/controller.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
        <form action="/" id="myLogin">
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password"ng-model="password"><br>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
    </body>
</form>
</div>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

For the js:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'dashboard.html'
    })
});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var uname = $scope.username;
        var password = $scope.password;
        if ($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {

        $location.path('/dashboard');

    } else
    {
        alert('wrong stuff');
    }

};
});
```

Some other data you may be useful to know is i have iis runing, the script is called controller.js and the html is login.html, as you must probably have figured out.
Thank you very much for your time and help!!

Comment: use `ng-submit` for your form and remove `action` which is what is pointed at root of site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-submit on form tag (and remove ng-click from button), and also remove duplicate inclusion of angular script at bottom (before /html tag)

Comment: this plus removing action in form solved it, thank you very much!